Deflection of an alpha particle between 2 bar magnets with opposite poles facing each other

The question I ask is where will this alpha particle deflect? Towards the south or north pole or inwards towards the plane of the paper or outwards from it?
This is from a Indian 10th grader.

Lorentz force

The alpha particle(positive) will be deflected out of the plane of the paper. If the particle were negative, the deflection would be in the opposite direction
Here a charged particle moves in a magnetic field, experiencing  a force perpendicular to both its velocity and the magnetic field due to the Lorentz force:
$$ \vec{F} = q (\vec{v} \times \vec{B}) $$
As you can see, the force depends on the cross product. $\vec{F}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{v}$. The force direction depends on the charge of the alpha particle. If the charge is positive, the force in the direction given by right hand rule. Otherwise the force reverses the direction.
Think in terms of paper plane:
If the charge of the alpha particle is positive, the direction of the force will be out of the paper plane. If the charge of the alpha particle is negative the direction of the force will be into the paper plane.
